# lyx - can't render document: Undefined control sequence

Tags: pdftex, lyx

I'm using debian testing and I update every so often.... after one update I made last week I've been unable to render a document I'm working on lyx.

The error on lyx says:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

What can I do to overcome this problem? I'm using lyx 2.3.4.2-2 and texlive-latex-base 2019.20200218-1.

Comment: Hmm... interesting..... I can click on `show output anyway` and (apparently... need to check thoroughly) I get the document rendered. Will leave the question open just in case to see if the error can be skipped altogether.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example .lyx file? https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Looks like some font (encoding) mixup (from the `fontenc` in the error message). Make sure your fonts are in line, any fontenc is issued before the fonts, that you aren't using some deprecated/incomplete font.